# Why this stack using super.isEmpty()?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

Why did I have to invoke `super.isEmpty()`? I have tried `this.isEmpty()`, but the debug process is paused.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stack<e>  extends ArrayList<e> {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void showPrompt(){
    System.out.println("Please input informations five times and type Enter between each gap:");
    }
    // `enter code here`


    public e peek(){
        return get(size()-1);
    }

    public void push(e o){
        add(o);
    }
    public e pop(){
        e o=get(size()-1);
        remove (size()-1);
        return o;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return super.isEmpty();
        /* Why did I have to invoke super.isEmpty()? */
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "stack"+toString();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Stack<String> s=new Stack<>();
        s.showPrompt();
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        s.push(scan.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Reverse order is:");
        while(!s.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(s.pop());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking why `super` is necessary, or why `this` doesn't work?

Comment: yep,that's what I mean

Comment: That's two questions. Which one are you asking?

Comment: Also please carefully read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - you don't need all that code to ask either of the questions (which are both duplicate of many existing questions)

Comment: I mean why not using 'this'or nothing,but using 'super'.?what's the business about superclass?

Comment: It the first time to use stackover,sorry to asking this terrible question,and my language is not English, I am a Chinese

Comment: The method is unnecessary. But if it's implemented, it has to call `super`. Using `this` would call itself recursively, eventually causing a stack overflow.

Comment: what silly I am!

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about this method:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return super.isEmpty();
}
```

First of all, this method as written is unnecessary<sup>1</sup>.  It is simply calling the `isEmpty()` method in the superclass; i.e. `ArrayList`.  If you left it out, calls to `isEmpty()` on a `Stack` would go directly to the `isEmpty()`  method implemented in the superclass.

Now to your question as to why `super` is necessary.  The answer is that if you *don't* use `super` here, and write it like this:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.isEmpty();  // INCORRECT!
}
```

then the `isEmpty()` method will be calling itself.  That causes infinite recursion, and leads to a `StackOverflowError`.  (If you looked at the stacktrace you would see a long sequence of stack frames where `isEmpty()` calls `isEmpty()` calls `isEmpty()` .... and so on.  Eventually, you run out of stack space().)

By using `super`, we are telling Java to call the `isEmpty` method implemented in the superclass.

---

<sup>1 - This code is not the standard implementation of `java.util.Stack`.  The standard `Stack` class extends `Vector` and is doesn't declare an override for `isEmpty()`</sup>

Comment: thank you,I finally understand where is wrong,**thanks a lot**